# ckeditor for expressionengine version 1?

Tags: editor, richtext, ckeditor, text-formatting, textarea

i am using version 1.6.7 , and i need to install a CK-editor to ability format the text in the entry process , and all the documentation said that i should be using at least a version 2 and larger, so there is any way to install any plugin ?

Comment: I hope Max's answer can help, but I have to say this: your CMS is 11 years out of date. I desperately implore you to either rebuild or put the effort in to upgrading your EE install. It is almost certainly running on a version of PHP with very serious unpatched CVEs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install MX Universal Editor, but I can't guarantee anything about this.

http://wiseupstudio.com/expressionengine/mx-universal-editor.html